# All methods work form POSTMAN, only GET from SPA

Tags: c#, .net, angular, api

I have web API, for typical CRUD operations. Backend in .Net Core 3.0, Frontend Angular 7.

I can send all the Post/Get/Put/DELET from POSTMAN. I can only sent GET from Angular application.
I set ap all method/origin/headers allowed in CORS in the API.

Code below

```
      [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Workout>> GetWorkout(int id)
    {
        var workout = await _repo.GetWorkout(id);

        if (workout == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(workout);
    }

    // PUT: api/Workouts/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult<Workout> PutWorkout([FromBody] Workout workout)
    {
         _repo.Update(workout.Id, workout);

        return Ok(workout);
    }

    // POST: api/Workouts
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<Workout> PostWorkout([FromBody] Workout workout)
    {
        _repo.Add(workout);

        return Ok(workout);
    }
```

Code from Startup

```
app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

Angular serivce that I'm using (remember that get method works fine)

```
    getWorkouts(): Observable<Workout[]> {
  return this.http.get<Workout[]>(this.workoutsUrl);
}

createWorkout(workout: Workout) {
  return this.http.post(this.workoutsUrl, workout);
}

getWorkout(id: number) {
  return this.http.get(this.workoutsUrl + '/' + id);
}

deleteWorkout(id: number) {
  return this.http.delete(this.workoutsUrl + '/' + id);
}

updateWorkout(workout: Workout) {
  return this.http.post(this.workoutsUrl, workout);
}
```

Browser error below

```
    HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "https://localhost:44322/api/workouts", ok: false, …}
error: {type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1", title: "One or more validation errors occurred.", status: 400, traceId: "|bc18502c-4f31b132dda79958.", errors: {…}}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for https://localhost:44322/api/workouts: 400 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://localhost:44322/api/workouts"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Comment: any errors? or bad response?

Comment: Try using debugger (chrome/firefox) for checking what problems you are getting. You can go to network tab in the debugger, and see for what errors you are getting. Few of which could be: i. If angular is actually sending that request or not. ii. If the url is correct iii.Any backend errors/header mismatch etc.

Comment: Error 400 Bad Request

Comment: Error from the browser debbuger

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "https://localhost:44322/api/workouts", ok: false, …}
error: {type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1", title: "One or more validation errors occurred.", status: 400, traceId: "|bc18502c-4f31b132dda79958.", errors: {…}}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for https://localhost:44322/api/workouts: 400 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 400
statusText: "OK"

Comment: It says "One or more validation errors occurred", did you check, before calling the service you are constructing the body `POST` request as it expects.

Comment: I solved it by adding "            services.AddMvc()
            .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true);"